# Argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, plist

I'm updating my app with the new iOS 11 standards and a lot of stuff were deprecated and now I'm stacked with this error: "Argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads.

Here you are the codes that was working:

```
//load plist file
    var palermoip: NSArray?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "palermoip", ofType: "plist") {
    palermoip = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
```

Anyone knows how can I fix it? Thank you in advance !

Comment: It compiles for me – which Xcode and Swift version are you using?

Comment: Oh... Pretty strange. I'm on Version 9.0.1 (9A1004)

Comment: That's what I have. Is the "Swift Language Version" set to Swift 3.2 or Swift 4? What is the deployment target? Can you reproduce it in a new project?

Comment: Deployment Target is iOS 11 for what about Swift version is Swift 3.2

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: I have done a clean but now I have more error the before... Mmh... I think that it's kinda of Xcode 9.1 problem... With 9.0 it was working perfectly ... Now I have Abort trap: 6 and segmentation fault: 11 on others swift files...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `PropertyListSerialization` and the `URL` related API

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "palermoip", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf:url)
let palermoip = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:Any]]  // or [Any] if the array does not contain dictionaries
```

and in Swift 4 even `PropertyListDecoder`